# Snakemake MissingOutputException when writing list to file

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm having a MissingOutputException with what I think is a very basic rule. I'm trying to print a list given through the config file into a file using some Python commands but Snakemake keeps throwing MissingOutputException error:

```
# --- Importing Configuration Files --- #

configfile: "config.yaml"

# -------------------------------------------------

scaffolds = config["Scaffolds"]

localrules: all, MakeScaffoldList

# -------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
        LIST = "scaffolds.list"

# -------------------------------------------------

rule MakeScaffoldList:
    output:
        LIST = "scaffolds.list"
    params:
        SCAFFOLDS = scaffolds
    run:
        """
        with open(output.LIST, 'w') as f:
            for line in params.SCAFFOLDS:
                f.write(f"{line}\n")
        """
```

Error:

```
[Thu Nov 17 14:08:33 2022]
localrule MakeScaffoldList:
    output: scaffolds.list
    jobid: 1
    resources: mem_mb=27200, disk_mb=1000, tmpdir=/scratch, account=snic2022-22-156, partition=core, time=12:00:00, threads=4

MissingOutputException in line 37 of test.smk:
Job Missing files after 5 seconds. This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait:
scaffolds.list completed successfully, but some output files are missing. 0
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it the Python code wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include Python code directly into your `Snakefile` you have to loose the quotation marks around your Python code in the `run` directive:

```
scaffolds = ["dummy", "entries"]

localrules: all, MakeScaffoldList

# -------------------------------------------------

rule all:
    input:
        LIST = "scaffolds.list"

# -------------------------------------------------

rule MakeScaffoldList:
    output:
        LIST = "scaffolds.list"
    params:
        SCAFFOLDS = scaffolds
    run:
        with open(output.LIST, 'w') as f:
            for line in params.SCAFFOLDS:
                f.write(f"{line}\n")
```

works.